# Can I change the order of the double integration?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f \in C_0^\infty $, $g \in L^1 $ . Then $$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y)g(y) dy dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y)g(y) dx dy  $$holds? If so, why?
($f,g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R $)

Comment: There is something called Fubini's theorem which gives the general setting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the finiteness of the integral. **Fubini's theorem** can be applied:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be complete measure spaces. If
>   $$\int_{X\times Y} |f(x,y)| \ \mathrm{d}(x,y) < \infty$$
>   then
>   $$\int_X \int_Y f(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}y \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{X\times Y} f(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}(x,y) = \int_Y \int_X f(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y$$

Since $f \in C^\infty_0$ and $g \in L^1$ I think it's safe to say that the integral in question converges.